# Create two lists from one by condition in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How simply create two lists from one using some condition in Scala.
Using filter I'll get single list, maybe some function returning tuple?

Comment: This question is not clear. You want to create two lists from a list of pairs? You don't know how to create tuples? What is the question? Post some example code that doesn't work and indicates your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called partition:

```
def partition(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): (List[A], List[A])
```

I guess this is what you want.

Example:

```
scala> (0 to 10).toList
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> res0.partition(_ < 5)
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```